# Check if files/dirs/ used in templates exists

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Given the following json:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
    name: {{ template "something.server.fullname" . }}
    data:
    {{ (.Files.Glob "dashboards/*.json").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
    {{ (.Files.Glob "datasources/*.json").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

How can I check if the folder exists and is not empty?

Currently, if the folder is missing or doesn't have any files, helm install will abort with this message:

```
Error: YAML parse error on domething/charts/grafana/templates/dashboards-configmap.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 6821: could not find expected ':'
```

Comment: Do you get the same errors if you use it inside "range" like in these examples https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files.md#glob-patterns ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pull your Globs out to variables, and then move everything within `if` blocks, e.g.:

```
{{- $globdash := .Files.Glob "dashboards/*.json" }}
{{ if $globdash }}
{{- $globdata := .Files.Glob "datasources/*.json" }}
{{ if $globdata }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: {{ template "something.server.fullname" . }}
data:
{{ ($globdash).AsConfig | indent 2 }}
{{ ($globdata).AsConfig | indent 2 }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```