# How to check if helm template exists?

Tags: templates, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm

I have task, which need to check if template exists as a file.
My structure inside common(lib)-chart:

```
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── _deployment.yaml
│   ├── _configmap.yaml
```

And then I need to check checksum of configmap. I found that solution, but has trouble, when configmap.yaml doesn't exist as a file.

I found that solution [Check if files/dirs/ used in templates exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991638/check-if-files-dirs-used-in-templates-exists)

I tried:

```
{{- $configmapexists := .Files.Glob "templates/configmap.yaml" }}

{{- if $configmapexists }}
test: {{ print $configmapexists }}
{{- end }}
```

And that return for me:

```
test: map[]
```

and it's doesn't work..
So i tried to play with .Template.BasePath, but I didn't get the right solution

`{{ include ("mylibchart.configmap") . | sha256sum }}` doesnt work for me, because we have configmap outside of lib chart

Answer (score 0):

according to the Helm docs at https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/

Some files cannot be accessed through the .Files object, usually for security reasons.

- Files in `templates/` cannot be accessed. *<-- That'd be your case.*
- Files excluded using
  .helmignore cannot be accessed.
- Files outside of a Helm application
  subchart, including those of the parent, cannot be accessed